# Product of Sum(POS) or Sum of Product(SOP) after Karnaugh map simplification

Tags: karnaugh-map

I am just curious on how do I determine whether a simplified boolean expression is in a SOP form or POS form.
for example this question:
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvnqV.png)

the answer to this expression is : NOT B.D/ ⌝B.D
and this is in SOP form
Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be a 'philosophical' argument. `⌝B.D` is the special case where the number of elements to be summed up becomes one.

You can think of `⌝B.D = ⌝B.D + ⌝B.B + ⌝D.D + 0.(anything)` which makes it an SOP.

Answer (score 0):

### Terminology:

First the theory, you can further study on Wikipedia ([DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)):

- **Sum of products** = **DNF** (Disjunctive normal form) = disjunction (+) of conjunctions (·) ~ *"the disjunction is not inside any bracket, but only
  as the root operator(s)"*.
- **Product of sums** = **CNF** (Conjunctive normal form) = conjuction of disjunctions ~ *"the conjunction is not inside a bracket, but only
  as the root operator(s)"*.
- **Full/Complete CNF/DNF** = the terms (products/sums) contains **all given variables** in either direct or negated form; the terms are then maxterms/minterms.

### Finding the right circles:

You can see, that the four circles in the Karnaugh map correspond to the four **products** in the original function in the same order (top to bottom, left to right).

### Given function as a SOP:

The function is now **in a form of sum of products**, because you can literally see, that there are four products.

It is also in the form of **sum of maxterms**, because the four parts contain all variables in their direct or negated form.

```
f(a,b,c,d) = ¬a·¬b·¬c·d + ¬a·¬b·c·d + a·¬b·c·d + a·¬b·¬c·d
```

For example the first term: `¬a·¬b·¬c·d` ~ if the variables `a`, `b` and `c` are logical zeros and only `d` is true, then the function's output is logical `1`.

### Minimized function as a SOP:

You can see, that the maxterms can be grouped and that creates the **minimal sum of product**: `f(a,b,c,d) = ¬b·d`, because all cells, where `b` is a logical `0` and `d` is a logical `1` are included.

The minimized function is indeed a SOP/DNF, because it certainly does contain only one product — the `¬b·d` — and there is no `+` (disjunction) operator inside that product.

[image: Karnaugh map of the given function - SOP]

### Minimized function as a POS:

The surprise might come when you realize, that circling and writing the function as a product of sums yields the same minimal form: `f(a,b,c,d) = (¬b)·(d)`, because there are exactly two terms: `¬b` (orange *circle*) and `d` (red *circle*).

Both are sums with only one operand. Because of that the minimized function is a **product of sum**.

[image: Karnaugh map of the given function - POS]

### Conclusion:

The minimized function `f(a,b,c,d) = ¬b·d` is both a SOP and a POS. You can check the correct solution by using [wolframalpha.com](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DNF%20%28%28%7EA%20%26%26%20%7EB%20%26%26%20%7EC%20%26%26%20D%29%20%7C%7C%20%28%7EA%20%26%26%20%7EB%20%26%26%20C%20%26%26%20D%29%20%7C%7C%20%28A%20%26%26%20%7EB%20%26%26%20C%20%26%26%20D%29%20%7C%7C%20%28A%20%26%26%20%7EB%20%26%26%20%7EC%20%26%26%20D%29%29&x=0&y=0&incParseTime=true).